N: Missing Signed-By in the sources.list(5) entry for 'http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu'
I am updating a relatively new Linode:
sudo apt-get update
but I get
Hit:1 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:2 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done         
N: Missing Signed-By in the sources.list(5) entry for 'http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu'
N: Missing Signed-By in the sources.list(5) entry for 'http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu'
N: Missing Signed-By in the sources.list(5) entry for 'http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu'

As far as I know this can be due to running unsupported versions of Ubuntu, but this shouldn't be the case with Noble. What is wrong here?
The contents of my sources files are as follows.
third-party.sources:
Types: deb
URIs: http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/
Suites: noble noble-updates noble-backports
Components: main restricted universe multiverse

ubuntu.sources:
Types: deb
URIs: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
Suites: noble-security
Components: main restricted universe multiverse
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg

I am running:
> lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release:        24.04
Codename:       noble


"/etc/apt/sources.list.d/third-party.sources" needs to reference a signing key.  As a linode customer it makes sense to trust their local mirror but the mirrored code should still be signed with the official ubuntu key you see listed in ubuntu.sources.  You can either edit the file to add it manually or you can use the following one liner.
echo "Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/third-party.sources


I had this problem with a sources.list file, and it was after some network settings messed up an update.
I did the following:

Temporarily moved the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources file to my home directory
Ran sudo apt update
Moved the ubuntu.sources file back to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ directory
Ran sudo apt update

That seems to have cleared out the problem.
